# Why is the Glide library displaying glitchy images?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-glide

I faced a problem while using the Glide library to display images within a RecyclerView in my original project. To track the problem, I created a simple app for testing purposes to determine if the same problem would persist or not.

[Here is a video demonstrating the problem on YouTube.](https://www.youtube.com/v/HdIZ8UU6xAk)

Although I have been using the Glide library for a considerable amount of time, this is the first time I have encountered this particular issue. Could you explain why the library is displaying images with a glitch effect?

**Here is the code to see if there are any potential causes for this problem:**

*activity_main.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerView_products"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:clipToPadding="false"
        android:overScrollMode="never"
        android:paddingHorizontal="2.5dp"
        android:paddingVertical="2.5dp"
        android:scrollbars="none"
        app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.GridLayoutManager"
        app:spanCount="3"
        tools:listitem="@layout/row_product" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

*row_product.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView
        style="@style/Widget.Material3.CardView.Elevated"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_margin="2.5dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:focusable="true"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="1:1"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/rowProduct_imageView_image"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:foreground="#66000000"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:visibility="gone"
            tools:ignore="ContentDescription" />

        <com.google.android.material.textview.MaterialTextView
            android:id="@+id/rowProduct_materialTextView_title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="start|bottom"
            android:layout_margin="7.5dp"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:lineSpacingExtra="0dp"
            android:maxLines="3"
            android:textSize="11sp"
            app:fontFamily="@font/font_bold" />

    </com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

*ProductModel.java*

```
package com.test.app;

public class ProductModel {

    private int id;
    private String image;
    private String title;

    public ProductModel(int id, String image, String title) {
        this.id = id;
        this.image = image;
        this.title = title;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getImage() {
        return image;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

}
```

*ProductsAdapter.java*

```
package com.test.app;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import com.bumptech.glide.Glide;
import com.bumptech.glide.load.DataSource;
import com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.GlideException;
import com.bumptech.glide.request.RequestListener;
import com.bumptech.glide.request.target.Target;
import com.test.app.databinding.RowProductBinding;

import java.util.List;

public class ProductsAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ProductsAdapter.VH> {

    private Context context;
    private List<ProductModel> productsList;

    public ProductsAdapter(Context context, List<ProductModel> productsList) {
        this.context = context;
        this.productsList = productsList;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public VH onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        return new VH(RowProductBinding.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()), parent, false));
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull VH holder, int position) {
        holder.rowProductBinding.rowProductMaterialTextViewTitle.setText(productsList.get(position).getTitle());

        if (productsList.get(position).getImage() != null)
            Glide.with(context).load(productsList.get(position).getImage()).addListener(new RequestListener<Drawable>() {
                @Override
                public boolean onLoadFailed(@Nullable GlideException e, Object model, Target<Drawable> target, boolean isFirstResource) {
                    holder.rowProductBinding.rowProductImageViewImage.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    return false;
                }

                @Override
                public boolean onResourceReady(Drawable resource, Object model, Target<Drawable> target, DataSource dataSource, boolean isFirstResource) {
                    holder.rowProductBinding.rowProductImageViewImage.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    holder.rowProductBinding.rowProductImageViewImage.setImageDrawable(resource);
                    return false;
                }
            }).preload();
        else
            holder.rowProductBinding.rowProductImageViewImage.setImageDrawable(null);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return productsList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public static class VH extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        private final RowProductBinding rowProductBinding;

        public VH(@NonNull RowProductBinding rowProductBinding) {
            super(rowProductBinding.getRoot());
            this.rowProductBinding = rowProductBinding;
        }

    }

}
```

*MainActivity.java*

```
package com.test.app;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;

import com.test.app.databinding.ActivityMainBinding;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        ActivityMainBinding activityMainBinding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(getLayoutInflater());
        setContentView(activityMainBinding.getRoot());

        List<ProductModel> productsList = new ArrayList<>();
        productsList.add(new ProductModel(1, "https://i.ebayimg.com/images/g/qZsAAOSwIRxirTew/s-l1600.jpg", "Fragrance One Date for Men 3.4oz / 100ml NEW IN BOX BNIB"));
        productsList.add(new ProductModel(2, "https://i.ebayimg.com/images/g/sqsAAOSwwIJkRBT-/s-l1600.jpg", "Office For Men Batch 3 By Fragrance One Jeremy Fragrance"));
        productsList.add(new ProductModel(3, "https://i.ebayimg.com/images/g/0E8AAOSwWcRkRWan/s-l1600.jpg", "Club De Nuit Intense Man LIMITED EDITION - PARFUM. by ARMAF Fragrance"));
        productsList.add(new ProductModel(4, "https://i.ebayimg.com/images/g/b4gAAOSwKwFkB6y~/s-l1600.jpg", "Chanel Bleu De Chanel Parfum Pour Homme 3.4 Ounces"));
        productsList.add(new ProductModel(5, "https://i.ebayimg.com/images/g/x-IAAOSwF~pkUtsS/s-l1600.jpg", "1 Million prive By Paco Rabanne Fragrance"));
        productsList.add(new ProductModel(6, "https://i.ebayimg.com/images/g/l8cAAOSwK2xkRsA7/s-l1600.jpg", "Followed 2023 By KEROSENE Fragrances"));
        productsList.add(new ProductModel(7, "https://i.ebayimg.com/images/g/ZIMAAOSw8ItjYU4i/s-l500.jpg",  "FRAGRANCE YVES SAINT LAURENT LA NUIT DE L'HOMME EDT FOR MEN 100 ml SPRAY"));
        productsList.add(new ProductModel(8, "https://i.ebayimg.com/images/g/ZfgAAOSwYJVkEuqu/s-l1600.jpg", "Tommy Bahama By Tommy Bahama Fragrance"));
        productsList.add(new ProductModel(9, "https://i.ebayimg.com/images/g/9j4AAOSwTFZiDhu4/s-l1600.jpg", "Vintage Davidoff Good Life EDT 125ml men's perfume"));
        activityMainBinding.recyclerViewProducts.setAdapter(new ProductsAdapter(MainActivity.this, productsList));
    }

}
```